# Why android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ below API 21

Tags: java, android, xml, drawable

Why I'm getting this issue below API 21? Though my project is compatible with below API 21 as mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html#vector-drawables-backward-solution).

```
//For Gradle Plugin 2.0+
 android {
   defaultConfig {
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
 }
```

So typically, I'm just trying to set a background in a Linear layout (**android:background="@drawable/bg_vlsm_config"**). Like this..

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toplayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_vlsm_config"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my **bg_vlsm_config.xml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="?mVlsmBackground"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I just need to set any xml drawable in any view or it could be used as icon also. But I'm getting something like this...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androcitizen.easyipsubnetcalc/com.androcitizen.easyipsubnetcalc.Activities.VlsmActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:621)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:670)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at com.androcitizen.easyipsubnetcalc.InputFragment.onCreateView(InputFragment.java:97)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:670) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at com.androcitizen.easyipsubnetcalc.InputFragment.onCreateView(InputFragment.java:97) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171) 
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/bg_vlsm_config.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080079
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2101)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:470)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java
```

However app is **working from API 21**. So can anyone help me on this issue. It's really annoying me a lot since 2 days. I still didn't find any appropriate solution. Thank you.

Comment: `mVlsmBackground` ?

Comment: yup, I need to set the background only. Below API 21

Comment: My question  what is `android:color="?mVlsmBackground"` ?

Comment: That is the my custom color attribute defined in the attr.xml

Comment: For test case set `android:color="@color/colorAccent"` instead of `android:color="?mVlsmBackground"`

Comment: Alright, after replace this android:color="?mVlsmBackground" with android:color="@color/colorAccent" it's working. So is there any custom attributes issue. Or couldn't I use custom attributes in below API 21?

Comment: thats not, for good approach you must call color code from colors.xml

Comment: Okay, that means I have to define those custom attributes inside the color.xml!

Comment: nope. attrs refer property must be of a color type, not a reference.

Comment: <attr name="mVlsmBackground" format="color"/> I've changed reference to color. I can't use ?mVlsmBackground attribute. WHY?

Comment: same error. How should I use that attribute? I have declared the attributes color in a simple theme inside the style.xlm. What to do? Help!

Comment: attrs refers color type not reference. you need reference. kindly use colors.xml

Comment: But what will if I change the theme? mVlsmBackground color should also have to change.

Comment: You can't use theme attributes in XML drawables prior to Lollipop. You'll have to use some sort of workaround for those versions, if you really need that behavior.

Comment: Thanx. I usually fixed that instead using theme attributes in xml I had to refer those drawables with my theme attributes. And also I had to create multiple Drawables for the same view. Bcz I had to theme, Dark and Light.